# Posterior probability of a player given that prior is Unif(0,1)

Tags: bayesian

Suppose a basketball player has the probability of $\theta \in (0, 1)$ for making a shot. In one experiment, the player keeps shooting the ball and let $x$ be the first time making the shot.

It is recorded in this experiment that $x \geq 10$. Assuming a prior knowledge that $\theta \sim Unif(0; 1)$, find the posterior distribution of $\theta$.

I know that $h(\theta) = Unif(0,1) = 1$, I also know that the posterior probability can be expressed as:

$$
k (\theta|(x_1,...x_n) = \frac{ L(\theta;x_1,...x_n) h(x))}{ \sum_{\theta} L(\theta; x_1,...x_n) h(x))}
$$

Where $L$ is the likehood function. However I am not sure what to take as probability.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

The prior distribution is $\theta \sim \mathsf{Unif}(0,1) \equiv \mathsf{Beta}(1,1).$
From what you know of the experiment, your likelihood is proportional to $(1-\theta)^9.$ Multiplying the prior density by the likelihood you can see that the posterior distribution is $\mathsf{Beta}(1,10).$

Because prior and likelihood are conjugate (mathematically compatible) it is easy
to see that the kernel (density without norming constant) is that of
$\mathsf{Beta}(1,10),$ so there is no need to evaluate the denominator in your expression.